# WINCEREL with special flags

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, build-automation

We have an underlying .h file in our platform code that needs built differently depending on if we are building the kernel or the EBOOT.  I am trying to script this to avoid the surefire errors that will occur if we leave it up to manually changing the file each time we do the EBOOT build.

Here is the part of the code that needs to change

```
// To disable debug port messages altogether, define DEBUG_PORT to 0
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PORT              DBG_UART1
#pragma message ( "DEBUG defined" )
#elsif ITT_EBOOT
#define DEBUG_PORT              DBG_UART1
#pragma message ( "DEBUG defined" )
#else
#define DEBUG_PORT              0
#pragma message ( "DEBUG disabled" )
#endif
```

Here is the build scrip that I have.  It works and builds the needed files but the build logs are always coming back with the DEBUG disabled message

```
REM Build the EBOOT with the changes needed for the UART 
REM Change into the directory
REM Rebuild the BSPCMN subproject
PUSHD .
CD C:\WINCE600\PLATFORM\iMX25-3DS-PDK1_7\src\COMMON\BSPCMN\
SET ITT_EBOOT_SWITCH=1
SET WINCEREL=1&&build -c&&makeimg
POPD

REM Change into the directory
REM Rebuild the EBOOT subproject
PUSHD .
CD C:\WINCE600\PLATFORM\iMX25-3DS-PDK1_7\src\BOOTLOADER\EBOOT\
SET WINCEREL=1&&build -c&&makeimg
POPD
```

The sources file of the affected project is here:

```
!if 0
Copyright (C) 2007-2008, Freescale Semiconductor, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
THIS SOURCE CODE, AND ITS USE AND DISTRIBUTION, IS SUBJECT TO THE TERMS
AND CONDITIONS OF THE APPLICABLE LICENSE AGREEMENT
!endif

!IF "$(ITT_EBOOT_SWITCH)" == "1"
CDEFINES=$(CDEFINES) -DITT_EBOOT
!ENDIF

TARGETNAME=bspcmn
TARGETTYPE=LIBRARY

NOMIPS16CODE=1

SOURCES=\
    bspargs.c \
    debugserial.c
FILE_VIEW_INCLUDES_FOLDER= \
    ..\..\INC\bsp_cfg.h \
```

Any help would be hugely welcome, I have been working for most of the last couple days to try to get the intended build behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by adding the SET before a clean sysgen. The calling the rebuild of the BSPCMN.